# Authenticate on browser and make a POST request

Tags: java, rest, api, post

I am facing an issue on my project. I have to send a POST request to a vendor's API. But I am getting the response login is required. 
The vendor has not exposed the Login API , but has given the login url. It wants us to authenticate on the browser and then send the POST request from our Java code. 
Can anyone please help us that if it is possible to this?

I have tried to launch the login url from my Java code. Then I authenticate it. But since I have authenticated in Browser's process so I am not able to send the POST request from my Java code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your work?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should make a `GET` request using the login url (a REST call from the Java code and not via a browser process) which would return you a valid access token or something similar, using which (ideally on the header), you should make the `POST` request which would allow the vendor's API to authenticate your request.

You would need to provide sample code and what you have tried for me to help you further, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: How can I make a get request to url with username and password ?

Comment: Check the signature of the GET request from the vendor. It may either be as params or a part of the header.

Comment: As I told, for login they have given us url and not an api.

Comment: Can you give an example of the url? You need not provide the ip address or dns name along with that.

Comment: What does the login process return? Is it a token or something similar, is it static or dynamic, and does it expire or not?